# Javascript typescript append special character to string is not working

Tags: javascript, string, typescript

I am about to append a string conditionally, with values coming from captured DOM elements. For cases of empty, I want to append the string with the character "¬". Although, this drives to append the string with � possibly because the above special character is not recognized.

Here is the code sample:

```
var nodeList = foo.childNodes;

  var str = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < nodeList.length; i++) {
    var item = nodeList[i];
    str += ((<any>item).wholeText || (<any>item).value || "¬");
  }
```

What would be the way to add the special character "¬" properly and get the desired result? Any help is welcome

Comment: That should work. Make sure that your HTML page and the script use the same encoding and the HTTP headers announce that encoding as well.

Comment: ... and that your font supports it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're appending the character as produced by your operating system in your default encoding scheme. How characters get encoded depends on the software you used to save the file with. UTF-8 is widely recognized as a good international standard for encoding, but you need to make sure that your software saved the file that way and then you need to include in your web page, a declaration to clients of how you encoded the page, so they can decode it properly. This is done with the following in your `<head>` section of your document:

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```

Even then, if you've used a character that is not in the Unicode character set, when decoded, it may not show the same character for everyone else.

To help combat this, you can instruct the client to produce many special symbols and characters can using an [HTML entity code](https://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref):

```js
let div = document.querySelector("div");
div.innerHTML = "&not;";
```

```css
div { font-size: 3em; }
```

```html
<div></div>
```